# Trazer contatos do smartphone

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Fiz um aplicativo para trazer os contatos do dispositivo. Minha duvida é o seguinte quando trago o telefone ele me traz um array, com o type:mobile, value="" com o telefone, como posso fazer um tratamento para trazer somente o número?

[image: Segue um print de como está vindo meus contatostexto em negrito]

```
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                {{contact.displayName}}, {{contact.phoneNumbers}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>


    .controller("contatosCtrl", function ($scope, $cordovaContacts) {

        $scope.getContactList = function () {
            $cordovaContacts.find({
                filter: ''
            }).then(function (result) {
                $scope.contacts = result;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + error);
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Como é uma array, você vai ter que usar o ng-repeat para pegar cada telefone, ou use {{contact.phoneNumbers[0].value}} para pegar o primeiro. Mas isso poder dar erro se não tiver nenhum elemento na array.

Comment: certo, vou testar aqui, @Rafael.

Comment: @Rafael ,Consegui resolver, usando da forma que você indicou e assim também encontrei mais um erro meu, tinha colocado uma chave a mais  
"{{{contact.phoneNumbers[0].value}}".
Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução para o problema, foi usando a posição do `array`, segue a baixo como ficou.

`{{contact.displayName}}`, `{{contact.phoneNumbers[0].value}}`

Comment: Marque sua resposta como correta então.